# How to make connection pooling for a web service

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jersey, database-connection

As an antecedent, I learned Java through online tutorials, so, please don't be too harsh with my questions, if I ask this here it's just because I don't know where to find an answer.

I need to write some simple web services, so I started researching and found the Jersey library which solved my problems for a while. The main problem was that every time I wanted to access a database, I needed to open a conection, so I researched about connection pooling.

```
@Path ("login")
@Singleton
public class LoginWS{

private DataSource dataSource;
private Connection connection;
private Statement statement;

public LoginWS (){
    try {
        Context initContext  = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        dataSource = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/testdb");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String authUser(@HeaderParam(value = "data") String data) {
    Gson parser = new Gson();
    LoginInput user = parser.fromJson(data, LoginInput.class);
    LoginOutput response = new LoginOutput();

    try {
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();

        // Here I do the DB queries, and logic

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try { if(null!=resultSet)resultSet.close();} catch (SQLException e) 
        {e.printStackTrace();}
        try { if(null!=statement)statement.close();} catch (SQLException e) 
        {e.printStackTrace();}
        try { if(null!=connection)connection.close();} catch (SQLException e) 
        {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    return parser.toJson(response);
}
}
```

As you see, I need to use a new Connection Pool in every other class I need to build, which I don't know if it's a good practice. So I whish to build something like:

```
public Connection getDBConnection() {
    try {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

So it would ask for a connection to the connection pooling, so all my web services uses the same pooling. I tried another Web Service which return the connection in a JSON object, but, I think that anybody who knows where this WS is will get access to my DB which is... undesirable, to say the least.

Then I read about an object called HttpServlet and I built something like this:

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; // No idea about this. Eclipse's suggestion
private DataSource dataSource;

public void init() throws ServletException {
    try {
        Context initContext  = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        dataSource = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/testdb"); 
        System.out.println("Connection Pool: set");                 
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Connection getDBConnection() {
    try {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
    }
}
```

Buy now, I don't know how to call this instance from within my Web Service.

Being honest... I ran out of ideas about what to look for.

Thank you in advance for reading this.

Comment: What server are you using?  because afaik in the "full" EE servers like JBoss and Glassfish JDBC resources are already pooled by the appserver?

Comment: Definitely research the EE server you are using. Most already provide the ability to setup and use connection pooling. If not, don't kill yourself writing your own unless you want to learn it. There are plenty of connection pool libraries out there that you can just use.

Comment: I am using Tomcat. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are currently using Tomcat, a wise choice would be to shift your development to Glassfish or another Java Enterprise Edition Server.  Tomcat is only a Servlet/JSP engine, but Glassfish is a full Java EE suite that not only includes Servlets/JSP and Jersey, but also the connection pooling you are looking for.

Here is one of many tutorials out there that show you how easy it is to set up a connection pool in Glassfish:

http://netbeans.dzone.com/connection-pooling-glassfish-nb

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: I'm very sorry that the link didn't survive seven years.  Perhaps there is another way that you can find a tutorial about how to set up a connection pool in Glassfish.